# How to color only one bin on seaborn countplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have this data and I created a seaborn countplot:

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

sns.countplot(x="class", hue="sex", data=titanic)
```

I want to color only the second bin (so the third and fourth bars) in orange and blue and leave the others in gray. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn's countplot returns an `ax`. The `ax` has pointers to all graphical elements of the plot, one of which is a list of the rectangular patches that form the bars.

You can cycle through the bars and test their x-position. As the x-positions are located around `0, 1, 2, ...` for each subsequent group, testing plus or minus 0.5 around 1 will identify the bars belonging to the second group. Then, just change the color of the bars fulfilling the required conditions:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", hue="sex", data=titanic)
for p in ax.patches:
    if not(0.5 <= p.get_x() < 1.5):
        p.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]